# RelativeLayout Imageview android:layout_height="wrap_content" not woking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

[image]

Here the i get stuck as the picture i gave is not aligned to top
there is a space in between the top bar n the picture.
Even i did not gave any margin or any padding values.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/udacity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried other images?

Comment: Yaa and got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scaling the image? try adding this to the imageView `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView is aligned correctly but the space which is seen, caused by the image inside imageview itself . So use "scaleType" attribute.

Comment: Maybe update the presented code to demonstrate how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i finally use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` 
n got the correct output . .
Shareing the code . .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/udacityImg1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/udacity"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```